# How to minify HTML code in one line Nuxt.js?

Tags: static, nuxt.js, minify

I'm wondering is it possible to minify the page source code to one line in Nuxt.js?

Answer (score 6):

I think nuxt has already minified hmtl itself. learn more in https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#html-minify.

if you want to minify css and js, try this one ini nuxt.config.js:

```
build: {
    html:{
      minify:{
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        decodeEntities: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        processConditionalComments: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        trimCustomFragments: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
        removeComments: true,
        removeEmptyElements: true
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The [answer from Prana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132400/2032974) is a step in the right direction. To minify the page source code to one line you should add as well:

- preserveLineBreaks: false
- collapseWhitespace: true

Note two last lines under build.html.minify in the code snippet below.

```
  build: {
    html: {
      minify: {
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        decodeEntities: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        processConditionalComments: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        trimCustomFragments: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        preserveLineBreaks: false,
        collapseWhitespace: true
      }
    },
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible to minify it to one line, but you can definitely do some minification of the HTML. Check out this part of the documentation:

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#html-minify

According to the authors, nuxt uses https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier under the hood, and there seems to be quite a few minification options to pick from.